# Simple line break after paragraph heading in memoir, or smallest possible positive length

Tags: sectioning, memoir

The default for paragraphs in `memoir` is to have run-in headings. I would like to change that to a simple line break, with no extra space below the heading. In section 6.6 of the `memoir` manual the `\setafterSskip` macros are explained, so I now have the following example which seems to do what I want:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\setafterparaskip{.1ex}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Now I am not sure if this is the best way of doing it. What is the smallest possible length I could give as an argument to `\setafterparaskip`? `.1ex` seems to be small enough, but is there something like a positive zero?

Comment: `1sp`, that is, 1/65536 pt.

Comment: Actually I decided that the fixed line break between paragraph header and text looks ugly, so I changed it to `\setafterparaskip{0.333\onelineskip \@plus 0.1\onelineskip}`

which is quite close but looks better.